# AngularJS ng-repeat example not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently trying an example from an AngularJS book, but it isn't working.
I get an error in Batarang saying:

ypeError: Cannot read property '#' of undefined

Here's the HTML:

```
<body ng-app>

<h1>Countries</h1>

<ul ng-controller="WorldCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
        {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}
    </li>
    <hr>
World's population: {{population}} millions
</ul>

</body>
```

And my js

```
var WorldCtrl = function ($scope) {
$scope.population = 7000;
$scope.countries [
    {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
    {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8}
];
};
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?
Thanks

Comment: you forgot `=` `$scope.countries = [
    {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
    {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8}
];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You have missed `=` after `$scope.countries`

Use

```
$scope.countries = [
    {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
    {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8}
];
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Thw9vs25oDOFA52unBhN?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

you forgot `=` in `$scope.countries = [ {name: 'France', population: 63.1}, {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8} ];`

Answer (score 2):

look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/konan/xaAxs/

```
function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.population = 7000;
    $scope.countries = [
        {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
        {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8}
    ];
};
```